# Problems Handling Bitmap in Android Studio

Tags: android, pdf, bitmap, itext

I am developing an app to do a lot of tasks related to images and PDF files. In one of the features I am converting images to PDF. I have encountered a few problems while handling images with bitmap.

1) When I am creating PDF file with images that I clicked using my phone's camera, for some reason they get rotated 90 degrees anti-clockwise automatically. When I am clicking the image, I used portrait mode, the image gets saved in my phone's gallery in portrait mode. When I view it in my phone's gallery it gets displayed correctly but when I load it in ImageView in Android Studio, it shows me a 90 degree anti-clockwise rotated image.
I am using the code below to load images in ImageView:

```
File file = new File(imagez.get(position));
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Here, "imagez" is an array that contains path to all images that are selected by the user in String format. e.g., "/storage/emualted/0/pics/...." like that.
This problem is only with images that I clicked using my phone's camera, other images that I downloaded from internet or from WhatsApp or Facebook all works fine.

2) My second problem is that when I scroll the PDF that I created, the images there loads slowly. The PDF creation is completed, the images should be there all time instead they load every time as I scroll up and down as if I am using an Adapter View to inflate a List View where non-visible items gets destroyed as they move out of the view and gets loaded again when I scroll back up.
I am using itextpdf class for converting images to PDF.

EDIT :
My question is that I want the image to be displayed in the orientation it was clicked, and when I am creating the PDF, the image should be saved as original (it should not get rotated automatically).
And I also a solution to make my created PDF load the pages quickly, if it can be done.
Thank you.

Comment: I did as you said @blackapps. Can you please answer my questions now?

Comment: `but when I load it in ImageView in Android Studio,` ? Do you mean: `but when I load it in an ImageView in my Android app` ?

Comment: You have a Samsung device by chance?

Comment: Examine the orientation of the picture. You can find it in the exif header. Then rotate the bitmap before assigning to the imageview.

Comment: Post your second problem in a new post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you are having is a common issue. I would suggest you to try the following method:

```
int orientation = 0;
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(path_to_your_image);
orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);

if(orientation != 0)
{
     Matrix rotateMatrix = new Matrix();

     if (orientation == 6)
         rotateMatrix.postRotate(90);
     else if (orientation == 3)
         rotateMatrix.postRotate(180);
     else if (orientation == 8)
         rotateMatrix.postRotate(270);
     else
         rotateMatrix.postRotate(0);

     Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(previous_bitmap, 0, 0, previous_bitmap.getWidth(), previous_bitmap.getHeight(), rotateMatrix, false);

}
else
{
     Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(previous_bitmap, 0, 0, previous_bitmap.getWidth(), previous_bitmap.getHeight);
}

//After this you can save your bitmap wherever you want
```

As far as your second problem is concerned I guess your images are too big. Try decreasing their size or dimensions to say 1200x1200 or whatever you feel right.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I will try it and get back to you

Comment: Thank you very much @HandsomeHunk. This worked flawlessly.